# Google Map API Javascript center map

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

i've set a Google Maps like below, but if I set '`center`' like that, i will not see the map! How can I do?

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check browser console for errors.

Comment: It seems to me that your html may not be correct. I once had the problem that I forgot to either include 1) `<div id="map"></div>` and 2) a height/width in your CSS for #map!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that 
position.coords.latitude and position.coords.longitude are numbers and if they are numbers try to reverse them , may your coordinates doesn't exist

or even more try to this

```
 var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
       };

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),mapOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Google map options you can set the map center.

```
var centerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(25.747688, 74.004142);
var options = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: centerPosition,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
```

Check out this fiddle for example map center [Google Map Center](http://jsfiddle.net/x8dSP/3890/)

Answer (score 0):

use,

```
 <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                 html, body, #map-canvas {
                 height: 100%;
                 margin: 0px;
                 padding: 0px
                 }
            </style>
            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>

            <script>
            var map;

            function initialize()
            {

                    var mapOptions = {

                    zoom: 13,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),//your co-ordinates
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };

                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

            </script>
       </head>
    <body>
       <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(centerLat, centerLng); 
map.setCenter(center);
```

Comment: Please add a little context to your answer.  Explain it so the next person to have this problem can benefit from it as well.